# Python: Why does `sys.exit(msg)` called from a thread not print `msg` to stderr?

Tags: python, multithreading, exit, sys

Today I ran against the fact, that `sys.exit()` called from a child-thread does not kill the main process. I did not know this before, and this is okay, but I needed long time to realize this. It would have saved **much much time**, if `sys.exit(msg)` would have printed `msg` to `stderr`. But it did not.

It turned out that it wasn't a real bug in my application; it called `sys.exit(msg)` with a meaningful error in a volitional way -- but I just could not see this.

[In the docs for `sys.exit()` it is stated](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit):
*"[...] any other object is printed to `sys.stderr` and results in an exit code of 1"*

This is **not true** for a call from a child-thread, where `sys.exit()` obviously behaves as [`thread.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.exit):
*"Raise the SystemExit exception. When not caught, this will cause the thread to exit **silently**"*

I think when a programmer wants `sys.exit(msg)` to print an error message, then this should just be printed -- independent of the place from where it is called. Why not? I currently don't see any reason. At least there should be a hint in the docs for `sys.exit()` that the message is not printed from threads.

What do you think? Why are error messages concealed from threads? Does this make sense?

Best regards,

Jan-Philip Gehrcke

Comment: I ran over this fact today and I wondered if this had been already reported in python bug tracker. I found it (your contribution) and I paste the link here in order that anyone else who falls in this SO question knows it has been already reported and can see its state. Although I don't think it will be corrected since this is from 2009 in python3.5 and today in 2020 with python3.82 has not been changed yet. [https://bugs.python.org/issue6634](https://bugs.python.org/issue6634)

Comment: Thanks for leaving this comment here Ganathor. Yeah... that story didn't go too well in terms of contribution experience. Shrug. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that the Python docs are incorrect, or maybe more precisely incomplete, regarding sys.exit and SystemExit when called/raised by threads other than the main one; please open a doc issue on the Python online tracker so this can be addressed in a future iteration of the docs (probably a near-future one -- doc fixes are easier and smoother than code fixes;-).

The remedy is pretty easy, of course -- just wrap any function you're using as the target of a `threading.Thread` with a decorator that does a `try`/`except SystemExit, e:` around it, and performs the "write to stderr" extra functionality you require (or, maybe better, uses a logging.error call instead) before terminating. But, with the doc issue that you correctly point out, it's hard to think about doing that unless and until one has met with the problem and in fact has had to spend some time in debugging to pin it down, as you've had to do (on the collective behalf of the core python developers -- sorry!).

Comment: You gave me a good advice, again ;)

Btw: It's so great that you share your knowledge here. I see that you currently spend much of your time to fill up this platform with pure expert Python stuff! This is what the community needs but that's not a matter of course. A very very big Thank You for this!

Jan-Philip

Comment: @Jan-Philip, you're most welcome, and, thank YOU for the kudos, it's always great to hear I'm being of help!

Answer (score 0):

Not all threads in python are equal.  Calling sys.exit from a thread, does not actually exit the system.  Thus, calling sys.exit() from a child thread is nonsensical, so it makes sense that it does not behave the way you expect.

This [page](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) talks more about threading objects, and the differences between threads and the special "main" thread.